# AMCharts show full chart with parseDates set to false

Tags: amcharts

i'm trying to display the full chart with AMCharts.

If i set parseDates to false, the chart displays ok, but i cant show the full period.

If i set parseDates to true, it behaves strange.

What am I doing wrong?

Heres a positions of the Json array used to show data on chart:

[image]

Chart with parseDates set to true:
[image]

Chart with parseDates set to false:
[image]

```
"categoryAxis": {
            "parseDates": false,
            "axisColor": "#DADADA",
            "dashLength": 1,
            "minorGridEnabled": true,
            "labelRotation": 30
        },
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that your timestamps are out of order. AmCharts requires that date-based charts with parseDates enabled need to be sorted in date ascending order to function correctly.

You might also want to set the [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) to accurately reflect the minimum period between your data; by default it's `DD` for days, it looks like `mm` is more appropriate for your data.

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "parseDates": true,
  "minPeriod": "mm",
  // ...   
},
```